# SQL Server 'In' versus 'less than'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table of addresses that I'm replicating.  There are 14 different types of addresses available. In order to cut down on the replicated data, I'm filtering on the AddressType field.  The field is an int, and has a value of 1 to 14.  I originally had a filter of

```
AddressType = 2
```

, as I was only interested in addresses with that type.  However, a recent change requires I have both AddressType 1 and 2 replicated.  I at first changed the filter to

```
AddressType in (1,2)
```

Would I be better off with a filter of

```
AddressType < 3
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It won't matter, go with what's easiest to type. It will only start to matter when you have hundreds of types on inputting and processing them.

Comment: if you look at the execution plan there is a little difference.

Comment: Agree it doesn't really matter. See [When is a Seek not a Seek?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/16/when-is-a-seek-not-a-seek.aspx) for why the second one might have a slight advantage though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be a significant difference as the numbers get larger. You won't see a performance difference at the smaller numbers but you will see a difference as it gets larger, especially if there is an index on AddressType. Your `IN ()` version essentially gets translated to:

```
WHERE AddressType = 1
   OR AddressType = 2
   OR ...
```

I do agree with the others for this specific case. (1) the performance difference when there are only 14 values is unlikely to be noticeable. (2) Jonathan's point that `IN ()` more accurately reflects what you want to do is a good one, also.

But for future readers who maybe have a lot more possible values, I think it's important to note how things *can* change when the list is not so limited (or when `<` and `IN ()` no longer offer the same functionality, e.g. when an address type changes). At larger sizes even when there is the convenience that everything in the `IN ()` list matches a range criterion, there are still other things to consider: (1) it is less convenient to type `IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, ...)` and this also can lead to a much larger batch size when we're talking about extremes.

Answer (score 4):

When your requirements change and you need types 1, 2, 9 and 14, the IN formulation will be better.  The list comparison more accurately reflects what you are doing (choosing two types from a small list of possible values).

The less than notation happens to work, but it is coincidental that the representation of the types is susceptible to range comparisons like that.

In terms of performance, there is essentially nothing to choose between the two.  The less than operation will perhaps be marginally quicker, but the margin is unlikely to be measurable.

Comment: I considered that. But it's not much typing to change the < 3 to  IN (1,2,3).

Answer (score 1):

Execution plans look identical. I'm inclined to say you should go with IN in case you need to add another address type like "5" that will force you to rewrite the < query.  IN is a lot more extensible because it doesnt matter what you add to it.

Answer (score -3):

All answers are fine...in the same vein as other posters...its "what else you might do" that might make a difference.

So always consider NULL in any comparison. Your query is fine wrt NULLS as written but: IF nulls are possible... and IF you decide to change or reuse the SQL ad hoc to say, Negate it...you might have an issue with the comparison as opposed to IN.

for instance how would NOT IN (1,2) perform vs >= 3  ... or whatever incarnations we might use. A NULL is TRUE in the first but FALSE in the second. (NULLS is comparisons).

Considering NULLS should be like breathing in SQL creation.

Comment: `NULL` wouldn't match any comparison other than `IS NULL`. Your statement that `NULL NOT IN (1,2)` would be true is, in fact, false.